# How to implement .psd to .jpg conversion using ImageMagick for a batch of files using Java

Tags: java, swing, imagemagick, image-conversion

I need to view .psd images in swing so I decided to convert that into .jpg and try to show it.

```
 My terminal command for single .psd to .jpg

 convert image.psd image.jpg (this is creating three images image-0.jpg,image-1.jpg,image-2.jpg)
```

but if I used

```
 convert image.psd[0] image.jpg (this gives me correct output)
```

But i need to convert .psd images using java. i tried this but it is not working

```
if (new File(_imageicon[i].toString()).getName().endsWith(".psd") || 
        new File(_imageicon[i].toString()).getName().endsWith(".PSD")) {
    File psdFile = new File(_imageicon[i].toString());
    if(psdFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("_imageicon[i].toString()"+_imageicon[i].toString());               
        System.out.println("_imageicon[i].toString().replace"+_imageicon[i].toString().replace(".psd", ".jpg").replace(".PSD", ".jpg"));
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("convert", _imageicon[i].toString() , _imageicon[i].toString().replace(".psd", ".jpg").replace(".PSD", ".jpg"));
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GridEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(_imageicon[i].toString().replace(".psd", ".jpg").replace(".PSD", ".jpg"));
        Image imagepdf1 = ii.getImage();
        Image newimg = imagepdf1.getScaledInstance(100, 60, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ii = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        _lbl[i].setIcon(ii);
    }
}
```

Any idea please suggest.

Comment: Where does the code consume the error and output streams?  See also [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html).

Comment: http://im4java.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For batch convert use this

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-format ", "jpg ", psdafterconvpath, psdpath + "\\" + "*.psd");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try {
        Process p = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

Comment: This code does not throw error but it is not converting but this works from command line as like "mogrify -format jpg psdafterconvpath psdpath/*psd"

Answer (score 1):

There is a space after format and jpg. Also add [0] to get the single image

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-format", "jpg", psdafterconvpath, psdpath + "\\" + "*.psd[0]");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DefineTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

This works for me. Check and confirm.